# Trying to find a childhood book where demons are summoned via fire and will power and new worlds can be created as offshoots

Tags: story-identification

I read a book as a teenager late 80's early 90's. There was a human realm and a realm of demons and they could communicate via fire, you could harness a demon power and magic by summoning them from fire and mental will power contest.
I think the demons infiltrate the hierarchy and there is one good demon who helps the main protagonist.
There was also something about the ability to create new worlds as bubbles off the main universe

Vague I know but I've always wanted to revisit the story as an adult if anyone can help

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129127/fantasy-book-series-boy-trained-by-wizard-in-a-tower (about the first book of the series with accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

The book you are looking for appears to be *[Riddle of the Seven Realms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riddle_of_the_Seven_Realms)* by [Lyndon Hardy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_Hardy).  This is the third book in the series following *[Master of the Five Magics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_the_Five_Magics)* and *[Secret of the Sixth Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_of_the_Sixth_Magic)*.

The story is of a demon (Astron) who is on a mission to solve the riddle of how to start fire in the demon realm.

Points of similarity:

1. Fire is used as the gateway between various realms (human, demon and fey being three of the realms).
2. Demons are contacted through fire and when summoned there is a battle of wills between the summoner and the demon.  This magic is called Wizardry.
3. One of realms Astron visits has a race which creates bubbles which contain new realms.  The heroes visit a few of these created realms.
4. Astron's boss is a demon that was dominated by the archmage in the first book and has started a new life based on creation rather than destruction.

It has been a while since I have read the book so I can not provide any further details.

Answer (score 5):

It's Lyndon Hardy's *Master of the Five Magics* (followed by *Secret of the Sixth Magic* and *Riddle of the Seven Realms*).

Comment: Can you give some book details that show it's a match for the question?

Comment: Thanks looks like these are the books, now to try and grab a copy again!