# Fantasy novel about a young apprentice switching professions

Tags: story-identification

A novel I read in the 90's or early 2000's.

The hero is a young apprentice to some version of telekinetic wizards. They can attract (or repel) parts of the same object. It is currently a siege and the master uses this power to destroy a catapult.

The siege is successful and the castle is taken. The apprentice escapes with a McGuffin. Now masterless, he starts investigating it.

He starts at the guild of alchemists and learns a few months. They finally figure out it's sorcery.

He spends less time at the sorcerers guild, possibly going underwater? He finally figures out it's some kind of demon summoning object.

Along the way, he learns to fight with sword and shield. His trainer pronounces him competent but too small to be a professional.

Finally,

> he trains very briefly as a demon summoner. He summons the arch demon, defeats it and gets on with life. A side plot along the story is the increase in demons due to failed summonings.

Obviously, this should be easy to figure out. Unfortunately, it is remarkably hard to google, as I found out.

Comment: Duplicate of this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/201786/book-part-of-a-trilogy-where-a-powerful-demon-makes-a-computer-out-of-lesser-d/201790#201790

Comment: Or maybe not  dupe? Technically the answer to the other one was the series, not one book. What's the protocol?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Master of the Five Magics](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31924325-master-of-the-five-magics) by Lyndon Hardy. This is the first book in his [Magic by the Numbers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43707-magic-by-the-numbers) series. It was originally published in 1980 so it had been around for a while by the time you read it.

[image]
[image]

> Alodar was a mere journeyman thaumaturge, learning the least of the five arts of magic. As such, he had no right to aspire to the hand of the fair lady, Queen Vendora, not even when he saved her during the siege of her frontier castle. But aspire he did.

The scene with trainer that you remember is:

> Cedric stopped and gently rocked Alodar back and forth. “You will never become a great warrior,” he said. “With more training you will grow into someone not to be dismissed lightly. But you are too small and slow to hack your way through a screaming hoard or stand toe to toe with a thick-muscled giant. No matter how hard you try, I do not see you someday beating your chest in triumph on the top of a pile of bloodied foes.”

The *McGuffin* that Alodar discovers in the besieged castle is a grimoire. More precisely he discovers a previously unknown spell has been written on the inside of the grimoire's dust jacket and he takes the spell with him when he leaves his master to become an alchemist.

Comment: That second Ed. cover! Reminds me of a nice guy selling self-published books in the dealer's room who apologized for the terrible computer-aided cover art he got from a random guy on Fiver. His cover looked like that 2nd Mot5M cover, but better. Oh, the failed demon summoning "side plot" was actually the main threat. The ancients knew demons would get out-of-hand and set-up the "McGuffins" to train a new master demonologist to banish them.